# IIS doesn't connect to libvlc audio stream

Tags: iis, stream, html5-audio, libvlc

I have created a audio stream with libvlc and the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private LibVLCSharp.Shared.LibVLC libVLC;
    private LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer mp;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        libVLC = new LibVLC();
        mp = new MediaPlayer(libVLC);
        Media media = new Media(libVLC, new Uri("http://listen.technobase.fm/tunein-aac-hd-pls"));
        media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:http{dst=:8080/stream.mp3}");
        media.AddOption(":sout-keep");
        media.AddOption(":no-sout-all");
        mp.Play(media);
        
        
    }

}
```

The stream is up and running and accessible via VLC and the following html5 audio element. The MIME type is also installed on the IIS.
If I now try to connect to the stream via the HTML5 audio element on my IIS server it doesn't work. I use the following HTML5 audio element:

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="http://localhost:8080/stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3" runat="server" />
        Your Browser does not support this stream!
    </audio>
```

Could it be that there is a permission issue with my IIS. What kind of permission need my IIS to access a local stream on my server.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the IIS permission problem. Your description of the problem is too little or there is no error message. However, in IIS, you can set the identity of the application pool as the local system or the custom account as the administrator, which ensures that it has the highest authority.

Comment: Please share logs

Comment: Here is the logfile: [https://www.file.io/download/?fileId=WBvKxewZXvKs]

Comment: cannot download these anymore, use another service

Comment: Try it from here please: https://www.file-upload.net/download-14406950/u_ex201223_x.log.html

Answer (score 0):

I partly solved the issue. The main problem was that my IIS side runs with https and the stream just run with http. If I turn off the url rewrite to https then the streams runs in my browser.
I just have to find out, how to create a https stream with libvlc.